# como recorrer los elementos de una fila en una tabla de forma individual con jquery

Tags: html, jquery

yo diseñe una tabla , y la idea es que cada vez que yo pulse el boton de una fila, me muestre por medio de mensaje el ID que pertenece a esa fila, pero sin importar el boton que yo pulse siempre me dice el Id de la primera fila. abajo les dejo el codigo, gracias de antemano

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>prueva</title>
  <script  type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
  <body>
    <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>nombre</th>
              <th> select </th>
              <th>Id</th>
            </tr> 
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Rafael</td>
                <td> <input type="button" class="show_Id" value="Show ID">  </td>
                <td><input type="text" value="1" class="Id"></td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td>Acosta</td>
                <td> <input type="button" class="show_Id" value="Show ID">  </td>
                <td><input type="text" value="2" class="Id"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>cedano</td>
              <td> <input type="button" class="show_Id" value="Show ID">  </td>
              <td><input type="text" value="3" class="Id"></td>
           </tr>
          </tbody>
      </table>
  </body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.show_Id').click(function(){

   var id= $('.Id').val();
  alert(id);

  });
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copio tu codigo y agrego el cambio en la funcion click con un comentario del como lo hice

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>prueva</title>
  <script  type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
  <body>
    <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>nombre</th>
              <th> select </th>
              <th>Id</th>
            </tr> 
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Rafael</td>
                <td> <input type="button" class="show_Id" value="Show ID">  </td>
                <td><input type="text" value="1" class="Id"></td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td>Acosta</td>
                <td> <input type="button" class="show_Id" value="Show ID">  </td>
                <td><input type="text" value="2" class="Id"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>cedano</td>
              <td> <input type="button" class="show_Id" value="Show ID">  </td>
              <td><input type="text" value="3" class="Id"></td>
           </tr>
          </tbody>
      </table>
  </body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  // vamos a subir dos niveles ->td ->tr y buscamos el elemento 
  // con la clase .Id que has definido y mostramos su valor
  $('.show_Id').click(function(){
    alert($(this).parent().parent().find('.Id').val());
  });
});

</script>
```

Comment: perfecto, muchas gracias

Comment: Si resuelve tu problema, marca la respuesta como aceptada. Saludos!

Comment: sii, gracias por la respuesta me ayudo de mucho!!